# PHP, MySQL - How to display correct time of posted artical depends of client timezone

Tags: php, mysql, timezone, php-carbon

I'm working on some website (news portal) in PHP and MySQL. I have a rubric last post with time when news are posted. My timezone and server timezone is GMT+2. I want to display a time correctly to all clients from all time zones. Example, if news is posted at `13:05` at my timezone to display for clients from `GMT+3` `14:05`, for clients from `GMT+4` zone `15:05`, for `GMT+1` `12:05`, and so on. How to do that? What is solution and what is a best way to store date and time in MySQL database for that purpose? I'm also integrate [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/carbon) in my website but I can't find method for that.

Comment: with js `offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();`

Comment: I have a low experience with javascript. Can I get with javascript from client PC (devices) timezone, and assign that to PHP variable as a string value like 'Europe/Brussels'?

Comment: No,  You cann't get name of time zone, because many of them have the same time shift. But you can get that time shift and change by js оr send  it to your server

Answer (score 0):

What we do in our company is we store all times in GMT. Even though we are in South-Africa. Then based on the user's location we convert the time to display correctly. There are a number of ways to determine where a user is located and convert the time, however the easiest method is to just ask them where they live and store that information.

Answer (score 0):

- Keep dates in timestamp.
- Store timezones for all clients.
- After establishing connection to database run query like that:

  `SET @@session.time_zone = "+02:00";`
  or
  `SET @@session.time_zone = "Europe/Warsaw";`

  Where timezone offset or name is value stored for client.
- All timestamp values will be returned from queries in defined timezone.

Answer (score 0):

While storing values in db store in UTC timezone something like below

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

Then while displaying the values get the user timezone using any timezone js and send the timezone to server using ajax and store it in SESSION variable and while displayin the date add that timezone.
For example 
1)Download the timezone js from https://bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect/src

Following will give you the timezone

```
var tz = jstz.determine(); // Determines the time zone of the browser client
var timezone=tz.name(); // Returns the name of the time zone eg "Europe/Berlin"
```

Make ajax call like below

$.post("scripts/set_timezone.php", { timezone: timezone} );

and in set_timezone.php have code

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['user_timezone'] = $_POST['timezone'];
```

and while displaying display as follows

```
$date = new DateTime('2012-01-23 05:00:00', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($_SESSION['user_timezone']));//This will from the session e.g Asia/Kolkata
$time= $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```